# Importing file into tailwind config

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm developing a rather big Wordpress theme. The theme is going to be used by multipe clients and i dont want to have one install per client on my machine.

Since using tailwind i have set the colors etc in my `tailwind.config.js.`. I was wondering if it is possible to do something like import a specifik clients config into a "main" tailwind config. That way i don't have to copy paste stuff every time i do some css changes to the theme.

I was thinking like (very pseudo):

tailwind.config.js

```
import 'my-first-client.js';
//import 'my-second-client.js';
```

Where the imported files holds all the configs. Doing it like this i only have to comment out the clients file that i am not currently working on.

Anyone having any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Presets

You could consider using [the presets](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets) feature of Tailwind. This lets you "package up a set of customizations that you’d like to reuse across projects."

Thus, if you had a file structure like so:

```
├─ tailwind.config.js
├─ my-first-client.js
├─ my-second-client.js
```

Where `my-first-client.js` and `my-second-client.js` are Tailwind configurations in their own right, you could do the following in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
import firstClient from 'my-first-client.js';
import secondClient from 'my-second-client.js';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  presets: [
    firstClient,
    // secondClient,
  ],
}
```

Or perhaps

```js
import clientPreset from 'my-first-client.js';
// import clientPreset from 'my-second-client.js';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  presets: [
    clientPreset,
  ],
}
```

## CSS Variables

Another approach, is to use [CSS variables](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables) as values:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
      secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',
      // …
    },
  },
  // …
};
```

And then set the CSS values in WordPress:

```php
function _enqueue_assets() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme-tailwind', … );

  $colors    = get_theme_mod( 'colors' );
  $primary   = implode( ' ', $colors['primary'] );
  $secondary = implode( ' ', $colors['secondary'] );
  wp_add_inline_style(
    'my-theme-tailwind',
    <<<CSS
    :root {
      --color-primary: $primary;
      --color-secondary: $secondary;
    }
    CSS
  );
}
```

Or have the client-specific CSS files with the CSS variable definitions in them:

```php
function _enqueue_assets() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme-tailwind', … );

  $css_file = '';
  if ( /* is client one */ ) {
    $css_file = …;
  elseif ( /* is client two */ ) {
    $css_file = …;
  }
  
  wp_enqueue_style(
    'my-theme-client',
    get_theme_file_uri( $css_file ),
    array( 'my-theme-tailwind' ),
    …
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue_assets' );
```